ggsurvplot - reposition strata color indicators of risk table
Is it possible to adjust the position of the yellow and blue strata indicators in the risk table when exporting to pdf format?
This is my code:
library(survminer)
library(survival)
library(patchwork)

lung <- lung 

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

ggsurv <- ggsurvplot(fit,  size = 1,  
                     xlab = "Follow-up time (years)",
                     ylab = "Survival probability (%)",
                     legend.labs = c("A", "B"), 
                     linetype = "solid", 
                     break.time.by = 365, 
                     palette = c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF"), 
                     risk.table = TRUE,
                     risk.table.title = "No. at risk",
                     risk.table.height = 0.2,
                     fontsize = 6,
                     tables.theme = theme_cleantable(),
                     tables.y.text = FALSE
)
ggsurv

ggsurv$plot <- ggsurv$plot + 
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Follow-up time", breaks = c(0, 365, 730)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1), xlim = c(0, 730), clip = 'on', expand = FALSE) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "white", size = 0.5),
        plot.margin = margin(0, 1, 0, 1, "cm"))

ggsurv$table <- ggsurv$table +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 730), clip = 'off', expand = FALSE) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 1, 0, 1, "cm"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.1),
        panel.grid = element_blank())

ggsurv$table$layer[[1]]$data$llabels[ggsurv$table$layer[[1]]$data$time > 730] <- NA

combined_plot <- ggsurv$plot / ggsurv$table + plot_layout(heights = c(3,0.5))

ggsave("xmpl.pdf", combined_plot)

I am aware of the hjust argument but it just repositions the risk table title ("No. at risk"):
theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 1, 0, 1, "cm"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.1),

This is what I get. But as you can see, the yellow and blue indicators need to be shifted to the left.

It is in line when I delete coord_cartesian = but then the y and x axis' zeros are shifted like this. Further, limiting the x axis is not present anymore.


The colored indicators for the strata text are added via the y axis text. Hence, one option to "shift" them would be to increase the right margin of axis.text.y:
library(survminer)
library(survival)
library(patchwork)

ggsurv$table <- ggsurv$table +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 730), clip = "off", expand = FALSE) +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(0, 1, 0, 1, "cm"),
    plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(l = -13, b = 11, t = 5.5)),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown(margin = margin(r = 12))
  )

combined_plot <- ggsurv$plot / ggsurv$table + plot_layout(heights = c(3, 0.5))

combined_plot



You nailed it! Thank you so much!
